# AWS EC2 Lamp Server "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access."

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cors, lamp

I'm currently hosting a PHP API page on an AWS EC2 Linux Lamp server ([following this documentation on AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)).  I was previously hosting the same content on an Azure Website but decided to transfer hosting - since this move I've been dealing with some CORS issues when attempting to access this page from my other domain (replaced domains):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin
'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried configuring my httpd.conf and .htaccess files to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header as I did in my previous hosting environment, but I can't seem to get the headers to add correctly on my requests.  Here are my current files:

httpd.conf: http://pastie.org/private/fxqyepmrfnyf4ljzt3vcfa

.htaccess:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, content-type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, X-Olaround-Debug-Mode, access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin, X-Frame-Options"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

However, when I check the headers on my request, I don't see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (but it is listed in the Access-Control-Request-Headers):

```
Host: api.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: https://www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-origin, authorization, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: https://www.example.com/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I'm guessing my .htaccess and httpd.conf files are not setup properly, but how can I go about checking this?  Currently I have no idea which part(s) are failing or where to begin debugging the issue.  The implementation between my previous hosting differs due to the OS of the servers, so I'm trying to figure out where I've gone astray.

Any advice where to look or what/how to debug to determine where the issue is coming from?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Well this is embarrassing - I thought I was uploading these files to my server but I later realized my FTP client was throwing permission denied for writing.  I forgot to change the ownership of the directories and was completely missing the error for writing, so my changes never went through.  It's working now.